# Absolute Path in React Native with Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to implement absolute path in my React Native App but I could not make it work

Here is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            "@/redux/*": ["redux/*"],
            "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
            "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"],
            "@/utils/*": ["utils/*"],
            "@/services/*": ["services/*"],
            "@/hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

And I try to implement like this

`import { roomActions } from "@/redux/room/roomSlice";`

and I get this error

Unable to resolve module @/redux/room/roomSlice from C:\Users...: @/redux/room/roomSlice could not
be found within the project or in these directories:

I tried to add absolute path with editing babel.config.js

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some problem with an alias.

Try to change the alias with this code and hope you will get your resolved problem.

```
alias: {
    "@/redux": [
      "./src/redux"
    ],
    "@/components": [
      "./src/components"
    ],
    "@/pages": [
      "./src/pages"
    ],
    "@/utils": [
      "./src/utils"
    ],
    "@/services": [
      "./src/services"
    ],
    "@/hooks": [
      "./src/hooks"
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! But it didn't work out either. My all files in the main folder. There is not a folder such as src in my project :(